# How to run advance Linux command on python script

Tags: python, systemctl

I want to get the string output of the following linux command

```
systemctl show node_exporter |grep LoadState| awk '{split($0,a,"="); print a[2]}'
```

I tried with

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output("systemctl show node_exporter |grep LoadState| awk '{split($0,a,"="); print a[2]}'", shell=True)
```

but the output is,
output = subprocess.check_output("systemctl show node_exporter |grep LoadState| awk '{split($0,a,"="); print a[2]}'", shell=True)
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

Comment: You have quotation mark conflict - `a,"=");` - you need to escape double quotes here, otherwise they close your Python string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

First of all, the function takes a list of strings as a command, not a single string. E.g.:

```
"ls -a -l" - wrong
["ls", "-a", "-l"] - good
```

Secondly. If the linux command is super complex or contains lots of lines - it makes sense to create a separate bash file e.g. command.sh, put your linux commands there and run the script from python with:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output(["./command.sh"], shell=True)
```

Comment: Thnak you very much. since my command is little bit complicated I created a bash file and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the double quotes (because they indicate the begin/end of the string):

```py
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output("systemctl show node_exporter |grep LoadState| awk '{split($0,a,\"=\"); print a[2]}'", shell=True)
```